# mysql WHERE IN with group by and order by

Tags: mysql, search, group-by, sql-order-by

I have an Innodb table `main` with 50K rows.

```
CREATE table main(
 id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
 main_id INT NOT NULL,
 feature1 INT NOT NULL,
 feature2 INT NOT NULL,
 feature3 INT NOT NULL,
 time_repetition TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
 rating SMALLINT NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (id),
 INDEX search(range_col1,range_col2,range_col3)
 ) engine=innodb;
```

POINT 1: 
`feature*` fields are some characteristics. So, during the search user can check that he wants rows from table, which satisfy several values, thus I need to use `IN` in `WHERE`: 
`feature1 IN (val1,val2,..) and feature2 IN (val1,val2,..) and feature3 IN (val1,val2,...)`.

POINT2: the table is denormalized according to repetition of time. Thus, I need to have `GROUP_CONCAT(time_repetition)` in select and `GROUP BY main_id`.

POINT3: The best value rating are desirable first. So, I need to have `ORDER BY rating DESC`.I also considered the recalculation of rating once a day and insert data into a table according to sequentially decreasing rating. In this case I need to have `ORDER BY id`. Unfortunately, it does not solve the problem.

SO, the whole query is:
`SELECT
main_id, feature1, feature2, feature3, GROUP_CONCAT(time_repetition), rating 
FROM main WHERE feature1 IN (val1,val2,..) and feature2 IN (val1,val2,..) and feature3 IN (val1,val2,...) GROUP BY main_id ORDER BY rating LIMIT 50`.

The problem is that query uses temporary and filesort in average to 5K rows. For example, below is the result of explain:

```
explain(select SQL_NO_CACHE * from main where feature1 in (4,5,6,7)
and feature2 IN (2,3,4,5) and feature3 IN (1,2,3,4,5) group by main_id
order by id limit 10);

+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type  | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | main | range | search      | search | 12      | NULL | 7333 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

If I add main_id in index it does not help. What could you recommend?

Comment: What is the reason for wanting to refactor this? It is really slow or causing a performance issue? - Really without some quite major Indexing (which in itself could cause extra problems) you're not going to get away from a temporary table or filesort with a multiple dependent 'in' query.

Comment: Steve, yes, I think 0.025s it is really slow.

Comment: you didn't quote 0.025s in your OP - how many times are you running this query to cause 0.025s execution a bottleneck?  You just wont be able to change this query to do a multiple dependent `IN` query with an order and not expect a temp table or filesort. If you wanted to factor these away you would need to change the database design and then you can question if `in` is even the best way to query

Comment: Do you have some proposals how I could change database design? Suppose that whole database now consists from only this one table `main`.

Comment: Without meaning to sound rude (that really isn't my goal) I is impossible to help you without some very clear and defined parameters. Firstly why is 0.025s too slow, what are you trying to achieve, how fast do you need it to be. This isn't just a case of optimizing database layout / syntax it might even be a case of moving out of the database entirely into a dedicated search engine. Please update your original question and you might get a better response.